# nodejs mariadb connection not disconnecting

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mariadb, node-modules

hi I am using nodejs to create a rest API

but I am facing a problem

first see code

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var mariadb = require('mariadb');

    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        var db_conn  = mariadb.createPool({
            host:"localhost",
            user:"root",
            password:"",
            database:"database",
            connectionLimit:1
        });
        db_conn.getConnection().then(db=>{
            db.query("select * from array_languages").then(data => {
                db.end();
                res.write(JSON.stringify(data));
                res.end();
            });
        });
    }).listen(8080,"localhost");
```

this code is returning the data perfectly.

But every time I make a request the connection is still open despite the request is finished.

[image]

**Expected Result**

Normally what heppens,
When ever I execute an script then after execution the MySql connection closes

**I have tried to close the connection**

by using `conn.end()`
but connection is still open

**I am from PHP Background**

In PHP if you request a page, after the execution all the connections will close automatically.
but here I am facing something new.

**How Can I close The connection after request finish ?**

Comment: You might want to use connection pooling, instead of opening and closing a brand new connection for every single query. https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections

Comment: @Tomalak thanks but I am using **mariadb** , not **MySQL**

Comment: MariaDB and MySQL are the same thing. (and you did not say which library you were using anyway, so that was my best guess - the suggestion to use connection pooling is valid either way.)

Comment: @Tomalak I tried mysql but it throws "Rethrow non-Mysql errors"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forget about this question.
But I tried to solve it today.

**Solved**

I was trying to close the connection but instead of this I should have closed the **connection Pool**

**Full Code**

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var mariadb = require('mariadb');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    var db_conn  = mariadb.createPool({
        host           : "localhost",
        user           : "root",
        password       : "",
        database       : "database",
        connectionLimit: 1
    });
    db_conn.getConnection().then(db=>{
        db.query("SELECT * FROM array_languages").then(data => {
            db_conn.end();
            db.end();
            res.write(JSON.stringify(data));
            res.end();
        });
    });
}).listen(8080,"localhost");
```